# Access a shared Win 8 folder from server 2012 in Hyper-V?

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

a preface: I've never used Server 2012 (S2k12) so I'm a total noob with it.

I'm running S2k12 in a Hyper-V VM (logged in as admin), and need to access a shared folder on my Win 8 host which has full access set for "Everyone" in the permissions. I have no issues ever accessing this folder with other non-server VM's. I've added the proper Workgroup name in S2k12 and can see the network from Explorer in it, but trying to access is brings up the Login Credentials screen; leaving the pw blank, or entering in the S2k12 admin pw just gives the "bad pw" message.

What's the trick?

p.s I don't want to have to create an actual User on the Win 8 host just for this.